Gazebo visual issues, first time startup
I am following this tutorial to install gazebo: Video by Articulated Robotics
Since I am running ros2 humble, I did
sudo apt install ros-humble-gazebo-ros-pkgs}

instead of
sudo apt install ros-foxy-gazebo-ros-pkgs

When I run the gazebo seesaw world with
gazebo /usr/share/gazebo-11/worlds/seesaw.world}
the world opens and is somewhat interactable (I can move things around, but the visual bugs get worse), but has huge visual bugs (see attached).

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3 on my laptop, following this tutorial on the ros page, I decided to try and get gazebo up and running. My guesses are that either I did not install something important yet, or that my computer simply has these visual bugs. (see attached image)
Following this tutorial: https://gazebosim.org/docs/all/getstarted
I got ignition fortress to install and run smoothly, but still not the prior.
Please let me know of any possible solutions.
